# How to count cells until a value is greater than 0?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I am trying to count the number of days until an appointment is available.

in the below data set I need to be able to count until a value is reached that is not 0.

the result I need is

- Example 1 = 3
- Example 2 = 5
- Example 3 = 0

In plain English I need it to check if cell = 0 if it is then count it, and stop counting when cell is no longer = 0

If there is a VBA solution that would be best but ill accept anything that works.

```
            Example1    Example2   Example3
May 13 2019    0           0          2
May 14 2019    0           0          0
May 15 2019    0           0          6
May 16 2019    6           0          0
May 17 2019    0           0          3
May 20 2019    3           7          0
May 21 2019    6           14         0
May 22 2019    6           0          1
May 23 2019    12          14         0
May 24 2019    7           0          0
```

I have tried multiple methods however the closest i got was with the below VBA which seems to give the right answer before crashing my excel so I suspect its counting something it shouldn't.

```
    Dim iCntr As Integer
    iCntr = 2
    Do While (Cells(iCntr, 3).Value) = 0
    Range("C13").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count("C:C")
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Did you try using a while loop which increments a counter while the cell in a column is 0?

Comment: If you have a good attempt, edit it into the question itself. Among other things, that will give us an idea of what the intended output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function DAYS_UNTIL_APPOINTMENT(ByVal OnThisRange As Range) As Byte
Dim rng As Range


For Each rng In OnThisRange
    If rng.Value <> 0 Then
        Exit For
    Else
        DAYS_UNTIL_APPOINTMENT = DAYS_UNTIL_APPOINTMENT + 1
    End If
Next rng
End Function
```

[image]

Please, note this only will work if you select 1 column of data. Also, I made it `Byte` type, so if the number of days is higher than 255, then it will raise an error. Just change it to `Integer` if you need it.

Comment: What is the motivation for using `Byte`?

Comment: According to [Data Type Summary (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/), `Byte` consumes 1 byte and `Integer` consumes 4 bytes. I got a *work habit* (not sure if that's correct in english) and where I work, due to long timing process, we try to adjust always. I must admit that in this easy process is not really worth it, but as I said, I'm used to it because my job. That's why I added later on an explanation about changing it to integer. Hope this throws some light.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works perfect. I am very new to VBA and surprisingly I hadn't come across functions yet but this forced me to learn and thought me a very valuable lesson, if your ever in Ireland i owe you a pint ha :) Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Formula;

For example 1 but editing returns the example 2 and 3.

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B$2:$B$11>0,0),0)-1
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest way is the next formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(0,B:B,1)-MATCH(0,B:B,0)+1;0)
```

Assuming we're dealing with data on column `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Public Function count_zeroes(ByVal columnID As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, columnID)

    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
       Do Until cell <> 0 'we'll keep counting until cell <> 0 
           i = i + 1
           Set cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, columnID)
       Loop
    End IF

    count_zeroes = i - 1

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if there are zeros all the way to the bottom of the column?

Comment: Well the chosen-datatype for this very reason is `Long` and not `Byte` nor `Integer`. Once it exceeds the `Long` maximum value (which is very unlikely in practical use), it would end up in an overflow

Comment: The problem is if there are zeros (or blanks) all the way down, eventually `Cells(i, columnID)` will try to access a nonexistent cell. Overflow isn't the problem. It is an edge case so is a bit of a judgement call if it needs to be handled.

Comment: Ah my bad forgot that blank cells get handled as zeroes, yeah should be ammened with a simple `isEmpty()`

Comment: You still have the line `Set cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, columnID)` in a situation where `i` *could* be `Rows.Count`. Also, the `isEmpty` is only applied to the top cell in the column. A quick test shows that your code crashes e.g. on a column which has a single 0 in the first row and is all blank below.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a match formula `=IF(B2<>0,0,MATCH(0,B2:B20,1))` with ascending order (edit:added if as this doesn't work if first day is available)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option using an array formula that works anywhere (at least I think it does) ...

```
{=MIN(IF(B4:B13>0,ROW(B4:B13)-MIN(ROW(B4:B13)),""))}
```

[image]

Be sure to commit using **Shift + Ctrl + Enter**